Prettier, in VS Code, failing to format SOME VF Pages
I'm using Prettier, along with the plugin prettier-plugin-apex in VS Code, to format Salesforce classes and Visual Force pages etc.
It works (formats my docs on Save) most of the time, but now some, but not all, VF Pages (.page files) are failing to format with this error:
[Error - 10:42:57 AM] Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined
  Code: -32603 

I've searched for this error, and even just for Request textDocument/rangeFormatting failed with message: js_source_text is not defined with nothing really useful returned.
It's really quite odd that it works for some files and not others, even though they have the same extension.
Any ideas what's going and how I can fix this?

Have you checked this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753330/vs-code-request-textdocument-definition-failed

@TusharJadav - No, I'd not seen this, but I think it may be the answer I need. Thanks!
